# In which rings does this multiplicative analogue of Bézout's theorem hold?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

When I was thinking about this question: [International Zhautykov Olympiad 2019 problem 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146237/international-zhautykov-olympiad-2019-problem-5) I learned that, when $0 < a,b$ are integers that divide $n >0$ and $d$ is their $\gcd$, then if for a divisor $m \mid n$, $K_m$ denotes the kernel of the reduction map $(\mathbb Z/n)^\times \to (\mathbb Z/m)^\times$, we have $K_aK_b = K_d$.

Note that Bézout's theorem (mod $n$) says precisely that the same is true for the reduction maps $(\mathbb Z/n, +)\to (\mathbb Z/m, +)$.

The proof I have for the multiplicative version uses the Chinese remainder theorem: do the case where $n$ is a prime power first, then glue the solutions for a given element of $K_d$ using the CRT. Slightly more generally, it shows that any PID $R$ satisfies the following:

> If $0 \neq N \subset A, B$ are ideals of $R$, then $$1+(A+B) = (1+A)(1+B) + N$$

I'm a bit dissatisfied with the proof for PID's, and would like to understand the equality more conceptually. So my question is:
Which other commutative rings $R$ satisfy this property? Is there a characterization?

Comment: Is the left set $\{1+a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$ and the right set is $\{(1+a)(1+b)+n\mid a,\in A, b\in B,n\in N\}$?  I ask because i'm not sure how you meant to define the product $(1+A)(1+B)$.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes. I denote $a * B = \{a*b : b \in B \}$ and $A*B = \{a*b : a \in A, b \in B \}$ for an operation $*$ - which indeed kills distributivity.

Answer (score 1):

The identity $1+(A+B) = (1+A)(1+B) + N$ is local, so it holds for every ring that is locally a PID; in particular, any Dedekind domain.

---

The below alternative proof that $K_a K_b = K_d$ generalizes to the ring of integers of a number field.

Let $l = \mathrm{lcm}(a, b)$ and embed $K_l$ diagonally in $K_a \times K_b$. The map
$$(K_a \times K_b) / K_l \to K_d : (x, y) \mapsto xy^{-1}$$
is injective. We have $|K_a| = \phi(n) / \phi(a)$, and the identity
$$\phi(a) \phi(b) = \phi(d) \phi(l)$$
implies that $|(K_a \times K_b) / K_l| = |K_d|$. Thus the above map is surjective.